# What does the notation $G /^r H$ mean?

Tags: notation

$G /^r H$

I saw this notation in an answer to a question and am not sure what it means.

The exact context is as follows:

$G=Sym(5)$ acts on the set $G/^r H$ of all right cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: It would help if you could include the context. It might mean the right cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Space of right cosets.  When $H$ is normal, you'd just interpret $G/H$ as the quotient space.  But when it's just a subgroup, $G/H$ represents a coset space.  But there are two distinct ones, so you need a way to distinguish them.  That answer used a superscript $r$ to denote right cosets.  I've also seen $H\backslash G$ for right cosets (and then $G/H$ means left cosets).